# Zend form populate function not working for select type of element

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I am setting up a zend form as:

```
class Application_Form_Ticket_Search extends Zend_Form
{
    private $_itemList;

    public function setItemList($itemList)
    {
        $this->_itemList[0] = 'Select Item';      // Default selected value
        foreach($itemList AS $key => $value)
        {
            $this->_itemList[$value['REFERENCE']] = $value['DESCRIPTION'];
        }
    }

    // Initializes search form
    public function init()
    {           
        // Settings POST type request
        $this->setName('search')->setMethod('GET');        

        $this->addElement('select', 'item',
                array(  'label'     =>    'Item',
                        'filters'   =>    array('StringTrim'),
                        'multiOptions' => $this->_itemList
        ))->removeDecorator('HtmlTag');

        $this->addElement('submit', 'search',
                array(  'class'     =>    'btn btn-primary btn-small',
                        'label'     =>    'Search',
                        'style'     =>    'margin-left:70px;')
        )->removeDecorator('HtmlTag');        
    }    
}
```

and in controller passing form's select box listing as:

```
$searchForm = new Application_Form_Ticket_Search(array('itemList' => $itemList));
```

and populating values(after a search request was made) like :

```
$searchForm->populate($filters);
```

when I debug `$filters` array, output was:

```
array(1) { ["item"]=> string(36) "201031999999992010051000000170430719" }
```

now the issue is with HTML: I received an output as(when a value was selected in dropdown):

```
<select name="item" id="item">
<option value="0" label="Select Item">Select Item</option>
<option value="201031999999992010051000000170430719" label="ELITE FRT CHWG N/AV GUM ST 15CT" selected="selected">ELITE FRT CHWG N/AV GUM ST 15CT</option>
<option value="201031999999992010051000000170430869" label="Consolidator" selected="selected">Consolidator</option>
<option value="201031999999992010051100000170450719" label="DAVID PUMPKIN SEEDS" selected="selected">DAVID PUMPKIN SEEDS</option>
<option value="201031999999992010051100000170450739" label="Consolidator" selected="selected">Consolidator</option>
<option value="201031999999992010051000000170430809" label="GARDETTO ORIGINAL" selected="selected">GARDETTO ORIGINAL</option>
```

Now you can see that every value is selected in dropdown and I always get last selected value. 
What I am doing wrong or what can be done for it?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
class Application_Form_Ticket_Search extends Zend_Form
{
    public function setItemList($itemList)
    {
        $items = array('Select Item');      
        foreach($itemList as $key => $value) {
            $items[$value['REFERENCE']] = $value['DESCRIPTION'];
        }
        $this->getElement('item')->setMultiOptions($items);
    }

    // Initializes search form
    public function init()
    {           
        // Settings POST type request
        $this->setName('search')->setMethod('GET');        

        $this->addElement('select', 'item',
                array(  'label'     =>    'Item',
                        'filters'   =>    array('StringTrim')
        ))->removeDecorator('HtmlTag');

        $this->addElement('submit', 'search',
                array(  'class'     =>    'btn btn-primary btn-small',
                        'label'     =>    'Search',
                        'style'     =>    'margin-left:70px;')
        )->removeDecorator('HtmlTag');        
    }    
}

$searchForm = new Application_Form_Ticket_Search();
$searchForm->setItemList(array('itemList' => $itemList));
```

Comment: It didn't made any difference :( similar result. All dropdown value got selected...

Comment: It should work. What do you get when you remove `$searchForm->populate($filters);` ? Is the "Select Item" option selected. Second, try changing the default option from `array('Select Item');` to `array('DEFAULT_VALUE', 'Select Item');`, Third, try setting a specfic value `$form->getElement('item')->setValue('example_value');` then `$form->populate(array('item' => 'example_value'));`.

Comment: I worked as you said. After removing `$searchForm->populate($filters);`  'Select Item' option was selected. I changed `array('Select Item')` to `array('DEFAULT_VALUE','Select Item')`. I think u made a mistake here. It shud b `array('DEFAULT_VALUE'=>'Select Item')`.Bcoz ur method added 1field in dropdown as DEFAULT_VALUE. `$form->getElement('item')->setValue('example_value');` is just for test na? but its not workg wid `setValue('201031999999992010051100000170450719')` too. I think the length of value is making nuisance. bcoz if i dnt giv it everythng goes fine with 0,1,2,3,4 values in dropdown

Comment: Yes that was typo. And yes `$form->getElement('item')->setValue('PUT_YOUR_VALUE_HERE');` is just for a test. If you think the problem is the length of the value, start with values 10 chars long, then 15 chars, and so on. If that turns out to be the problem then it's a bug in zf so you need to file it in the [bug tracker](http://framework.zend.com/issues/secure/Dashboard.jspa).

Comment: BullfrogBlues : I checked and setValue is setting even 45 character long dropdown value, so ZF seem that much of handling those things :) ;p But the issue is, why its selecting all values. I think its dynamic population issue now.Let me search and explore more...